# Do golden color pine trees associate with the name of Fluffy?

Tags: trees, forests, tree-identification

I went to a nursery over the weekend and purchased a golden colored pine tree. The nursery was calling them  ***Fluffy Trees*** (picture below). This tree name really makes me laugh and smile but I am having a hard time believing that is what it is actually called. In fact I went online and found that the name could be [Wate's Golden Pine](https://www.monrovia.com/plant-catalog/plants/632/wates-golden-pine/#:%7E:text=Pinus%20virginiana%20%27Wate%27s%20Golden%27&text=Glows%20in%20the%20winter%20landscape,a%20focal%20point%20in%20winter.). Would someone be able to identify this tree and confirm if the word ***Fluffy*** is appropriately associated with this specie of tree?

[image]

Comment: Isn't there a tag on the trunk telling you exactly what it is? Or is the nursery just selling "fluffy trees".

Comment: I would assume the shop just has a descriptive tag, rather than trying to imply they are called "fluffy trees"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you have there is almost certainly a variety of *[Chameacyparis lawsoniana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chamaecyparis_lawsoniana)*. These trees are characterized by the flattened scale-like leaves in a fairly dense branching cluster. Wate's golden pine is a *Pinus* species, all of which have needles for leaves, like you might see on a classic christmas tree.

As to which variety it is - there are lots of them, some of them are yellow (it'll turn green in the middle, retaining yellow on the new foliage), so I can't tell from a photo, and for some it takes some aging to see the true colours and size come through.

I have never heard of them called "Fluffy" trees before, though the foliage is described as fluffy by a few places, based on a quick google search.

Comment: thank you again for the informative answer!